# Facing error 'callbacks.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function'

Tags: javascript, asynccallback

I am trying to print a message 'Successfully generated 10 numbers' once the numbers till 10 are printed, but facing the issue Facing error **'callbacks.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function'** even after i passed callback function in the argument.

***callbacks.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>JS - Asynchronous - Callbacks</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<h3>Number generator till 15</h3>
<p id="num"></p>

<h3>Message</h3>
<p id="msg"></p>
<script src="callbacks.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***callbacks.js:***

```
var a = setInterval(gen, 1000);
let n = 0;

function gen(callback){
    n = n + 1;
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = n;

    if ( n == 10){
        clearInterval(a);
    }

    callback();
}

function printMessage(){
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Succesfully generated 10 numbers';
}

gen(printMessage);
```

Comment: `setInterval(gen, 1000);` there's no callback argument to `gen` here.

Answer (score 0):

change `var a = setInterval(gen, 1000);` to:

```js
var a = setInterval(function () {
    gen(printMessage);
}, 1000);
```

this will call gen with the callback parameter assigned correctly, in a second-long interval.

Comment: Modified code as per your suggestion, but my output is not as expected. I was expecting the message 'Succesfully generated 10 numbers' to be printed out after the completion of gen() function which has to generate/prints till 10 numbers.

Comment: Output is: 

Number generator till 15
10

Message
Succesfully generated 10 numbers

My expected output is:
Number generator till 15
10  //continues to increment and print from 1 to 10. After printing number 10, it will stop and then display the message as 'Succesfully generated 10 numbers' in <p> tag of id msg. (But, the msg is displaying righ after the page is loaded, i don't want to use setTimeOut() function here, but want my gen() function to print until 10 numbers first and then printMessage() function has to be run.

Comment: Thanks for your time, after analysis found that callback(); function is running for each second, hence printing every time. I added callback(); function once it reaches number 10 and it worked. Just changed if loop

if ( n == 10){
        clearInterval(a);
        callback();
    }